# c# progress bar does not update

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I am trying to do a progress bar in c# but I am having trouble updating it gets to 90% and resets. but if I show a message box then it will fill up.
This code fills it all the way up

```
    public void mess(string s)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("l");
    }
    public void ProgressForm1Method(double min, double max)
    {
        ts.Maximum = (int)max;
        ts.Value = (int)min;
        this.Update();
        Application.DoEvents();
        if (ts.Value == ts.Maximum)
        {
            mess("l");
            ts.Value = 0;
        }
        ts.Invalidate();
    }
```

this does not

```
    public void mess(string s)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("l");
    }
    public void ProgressForm1Method(double min, double max)
    {
        ts.Maximum = (int)max;
        ts.Value = (int)min;
        this.Update();
        Application.DoEvents();
        if (ts.Value == ts.Maximum)
        {
            ts.Value = 0;
        }
        ts.Invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: That's because you reset the value back to 0 once it hits max. Using a message box shows it at 100 before you reset it to 0

Comment: simple debugging or just reading your code should have made this very clear...

Comment: @The8thBit - Submit that as an answer.

Comment: if I take out ts.Value = 0 and put in Thread.Sleep it still does not update all the way

Comment: How long of a sleep did you put in?

Comment: 10000 I use this then I call the progress bar method again

Answer (score 3):

That's because you set the value to 0 the moment it hits maximum. So it gives you the impression that it only fills up to 90%. Whereas, in your first example, you show the message box right before `ts.Value = 0`.

`ts.Value = 0` doesn't fire until you click close the message box, so it shows up to 100%